# stop redraw chart when chart types changes in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using three chart types Line, OHLC, Candlestick in highcharts.

I kept those options in buttons. I'm also drawing vertical and horizontal lines on charts.

The problem is, whenever I  change chart type, objects(I mean the vertical and horizontal lines) should remain there.

But it just refreshed. I didn't use  `chart.redraw()` function. I just call the method each time chart type is selected. Is there anyway if I change charts, objects should remain there?

```
function chart(type,printSma,linked,line,algo)
{       

    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                        credits: {
                            enabled : 0
                        },

                        rangeSelector : {
                            buttons: [{
                                type: 'month',
                                count: 1,
                                text: '1M'
                            }, {
                                type: 'month',
                                count: 3,
                                text: '3M'
                            },{
                                type: 'month',
                                count: 6,
                                text: '6M'
                            },{
                                type: 'all',
                                text: 'All'
                            }], 
                            selected:3      
                        },

                        legend: {
                            enabled: true,
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            align: 'right',
                            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                            borderWidth: 0
                        },

                        title : {
                            text : currecny
                        },

                        xAxis :{
                            ordinal: false,
                            minRange : 3600000,

                        },

                         yAxis : [{
                              offset: 0,
                              ordinal: false,
                              height:280,

                              labels: {
                                format: '{value:.5f}'
                                    }

                         }],



                        chart: {                        
                            events: {




                                click: function(event) {


                                    var ren = this.renderer;
                                    //if(event.ctrlKey)
                                    if(line_type=='vertical')
                                    {


                                        chartt ='';
                                        axis_value='';
                                        chartt = this.xAxis[0];
                                        axis_value=event.xAxis[0].value;
                                        $("#line_popup_vertical").show();
                                        $('#save_line_vertical').click(function(event) {

                                            var label=document.getElementById("line_label_vertical").value;
                                            if(label!=null)
                                            {
                                                var id = 'vertLine' + Math.random();
                                                chartt.addPlotLine({
                                                                    value: axis_value,
                                                                    color: '#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
                                                                    width: 2,
                                                                    id: id,
                                                                    label : {
                                                                        text : label
                                                                            },
                                                                    events: {
                                                                        click: function(e) {
                                                                            //this.axis.removePlotLine(this.id);
                                                                            chartt.removePlotLine(id);
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                });
                                            }
                                            line_type="";
                                            document.getElementById("line_label_vertical").value="";
                                            $("#horizontal").removeClass("horizontal_hover");
                                            $("#vertical").removeClass("vertical_hover");
                                            $("#trend").removeClass("trend_hover");
                                            $("#fibo").removeClass("fibo_hover");
                                            $("#pointer").addClass("pointer_hover");
                                            $("#line_popup_vertical").fadeOut();

                                        });


                                    }


                                    /*else if(event.altKey)
                                    {*/
                                    else if(line_type=='horizontal')
                                    {
                                        chartt ='';
                                        axis_value='';
                                        chartt = this.yAxis[0];
                                        axis_value=event.yAxis[0].value;
                                        $("#line_popup_horizontal").show();
                                        $('#save_line_horizontal').click(function(event) {

                                            var label=document.getElementById("line_label_horizontal").value;
                                            if(label!=null)
                                            {
                                                var id = 'horzLine' + Math.random();
                                                chartt.addPlotLine({
                                                                    value: axis_value,
                                                                    color: '#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
                                                                    width: 2,
                                                                    id: id,
                                                                    label : {
                                                                        text : label
                                                                            },
                                                                    events: {
                                                                        click: function(e) {
                                                                            //this.axis.removePlotLine(this.id);
                                                                            chartt.removePlotLine(id);
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                });
                                            }




                                        /*var label=prompt('Label for Horizontal Line');
                                        if(label!=null)
                                        {
                                            //chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('horzLine');
                                            var chart ='';
                                            var id = 'horzLine' + Math.random();
                                            chart = this.yAxis[0];                                      
                                            chart.addPlotLine({
                                                value: event.yAxis[0].value,
                                                dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                                                color: '#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
                                                width: 2,
                                                id: id,
                                                label : {
                                                    text : label
                                                },

                                                events: {
                                                    click: function(e) {
                                                        //this.axis.removePlotLine(this.id);
                                                        chart.removePlotLine(id); 
                                                    }
                                                },

                                            });

                                        }*/

                                        line_type="";
                                        document.getElementById("line_label_horizontal").value="";
                                        $("#horizontal").removeClass("horizontal_hover");
                                        $("#vertical").removeClass("vertical_hover");
                                        $("#trend").removeClass("trend_hover");
                                        $("#fibo").removeClass("fibo_hover");
                                        $("#pointer").addClass("pointer_hover");
                                        $("#line_popup_horizontal").fadeOut();
                                        });

                                    }

                                    //else if(clickDetected)
                                    else if(line_type=='trend')
                                    {

                                        var x1=event.xAxis[0].value;
                                        var x2 = this.xAxis[0].toPixels(x1);                
                                        var y1=event.yAxis[0].value;
                                        var y2 = this.yAxis[0].toPixels(y1);

                                        /*ren.circle(x2, y2, 5).attr({
                                            'stroke-width': 2,
                                            stroke: 'red',
                                            fill: '#636363',
                                            zIndex: 3
                                        }).add();*/


                                        selected_point='['+x1+','+y1+']';                           
                                        all_points.push(selected_point);
                                        all_str=all_points.toString();                                  
                                        if(all_points.length>1)
                                        {
                                            //this.series[1].remove();
                                            this.addSeries({                            
                                            type : 'line',
                                            name : 'Trendline'+(j++),
                                            id: 'trend',    
                                            data: JSON.parse("[" + all_str + "]"),                      
                                            color:'#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
                                            marker:{enabled:true}
                                            });

                                            //$("#horizontal").removeClass("horizontal_hover");
                                            //$("#vertical").removeClass("vertical_hover");
                                            $("#trend").removeClass("trend_hover");
                                            //$("#fibo").removeClass("fibo_hover");
                                            $("#pointer").addClass("pointer_hover");
                                            $("#pointer").click();

                                        }

                                    }

                                    if(all_points.length==2)
                                    {
                                        all_points=[];
                                    }       
                                },

                            },                                                                      
                        },

                        plotOptions: {
                            line: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function(event) {

                                        this.remove();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            series: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function(event) {

                                    //For Other Lines
                                    if(line_type=='vertical')
                                    {
                                        chartt ='';
                                        axis_value='';
                                        chartt = this.xAxis;
                                        axis_value=chartt.toValue(event.chartX);
                                        $("#line_popup_vertical").show();
                                        $('#save_line_vertical').click(function(event) {

                                            var label=document.getElementById("line_label_vertical").value;
                                            if(label!=null)
                                            {
                                                var id = 'vertLine' + Math.random();
                                                chartt.addPlotLine({
                                                                    value: axis_value,
                                                                    color: '#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
                                                                    width: 2,
                                                                    id: id,
                                                                    label : {
                                                                        text : label
                                                                            },
                                                                    events: {
                                                                        click: function(e) {
                                                                            //this.axis.removePlotLine(this.id);
                                                                            chartt.removePlotLine(id);
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                });
                                            }
                                            line_type="";
                                            document.getElementById("line_label_vertical").value="";
                                            $("#horizontal").removeClass("horizontal_hover");
                                            $("#vertical").removeClass("vertical_hover");
                                            $("#trend").removeClass("trend_hover");
                                            $("#fibo").removeClass("fibo_hover");
                                            $("#pointer").addClass("pointer_hover");
                                            $("#line_popup_vertical").fadeOut();

                                        });


                                    }

                                    else if(line_type=='horizontal')
                                    {
                                        chartt ='';
                                        axis_value='';
                                        chartt = this.yAxis;
                                        axis_value=chartt.toValue(event.chartY);
                                        $("#line_popup_horizontal").show();
                                        $('#save_line_horizontal').click(function(event){

                                            var label=document.getElementById("line_label_horizontal").value;
                                            if(label!=null)
                                            {
                                                var id = 'horzLine' + Math.random();
                                                chartt.addPlotLine({
                                                                    value: axis_value,
                                                                    color: '#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
                                                                    width: 2,
                                                                    id: id,
                                                                    label : {
                                                                        text : label
                                                                            },
                                                                    events: {
                                                                        click: function(e) {
                                                                            //this.axis.removePlotLine(this.id);
                                                                            chartt.removePlotLine(id);
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                });
                                            }

                                        line_type="";
                                        document.getElementById("line_label_horizontal").value="";
                                        $("#horizontal").removeClass("horizontal_hover");
                                        $("#vertical").removeClass("vertical_hover");
                                        $("#trend").removeClass("trend_hover");
                                        $("#fibo").removeClass("fibo_hover");
                                        $("#pointer").addClass("pointer_hover");
                                        $("#line_popup_horizontal").fadeOut();
                                        });

                                    }

                                    //else if(clickDetected)
                                    else if(line_type=='trend')
                                    {

                                        var x1=chartt.toValue(event.chartX);
                                        //var x2 = this.xAxis[0].toPixels(x1);              
                                        var y1=chartt.toValue(event.chartY);
                                        //var y2 = this.yAxis[0].toPixels(y1);

                                        selected_point='['+x1+','+y1+']';                           
                                        all_points.push(selected_point);
                                        all_str=all_points.toString();                                  
                                        if(all_points.length>1)
                                        {
                                            //this.series[1].remove();
                                            this.addSeries({                            
                                            type : 'line',
                                            name : 'Trendline'+(j++),
                                            id: 'trend',    
                                            data: JSON.parse("[" + all_str + "]"),                      
                                            color:'#'+(Math.random()*0xEEEEEE<<0).toString(16),
                                            marker:{enabled:true}
                                            });

                                            //$("#horizontal").removeClass("horizontal_hover");
                                            //$("#vertical").removeClass("vertical_hover");
                                            $("#trend").removeClass("trend_hover");
                                            //$("#fibo").removeClass("fibo_hover");
                                            $("#pointer").addClass("pointer_hover");
                                            $("#pointer").click();

                                        }

                                    }

                                    if(all_points.length==2)
                                    {
                                        all_points=[];
                                    }                                   


                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },



                        series : [

                        {
                            //allowPointSelect : true,
                            type : type,
                            name : 'Stock Price',
                            id: 'primary',
                            data : onadata,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueDecimals: 2,
                                crosshairs: true,
                                shared: true
                            },
                            dataGrouping : {
                                units : [
                                    [
                                        'hour',
                                        [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12]
                                    ], [
                                        'day',
                                        [1]
                                    ], [
                                        'week',
                                        [1]
                                    ], [
                                        'month',
                                        [1, 3, 6]
                                    ], [
                                        'year',
                                        [1]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            }
                        },                  

                        ]
                    });
}

    $('#chart').find('input[name="selection"]').each(function(index, element) {
                $(this).click(function(e) {
                    //console.log('I was clicked'); 
                    type=$(this).val();

                        printSma=true;
                        linked='primary';
                        period=15;
                        algo='SMA';
                        typ='trendline';

                    if(type=='line')
                    {
                        $(this).addClass("active_linee");
                        $("#ohlcc").removeClass("active_ohlcc");
                        $("#candlestickk").removeClass("active_candlestickk");

                        //$("#indicator_list").show();
                        //$("#indicator_list").removeClass('indicator_list_hover');


                    }

                    else if(type=='ohlc')
                    {
                        $(this).addClass("active_ohlcc");
                        $("#linee").removeClass("active_linee");
                        $("#candlestickk").removeClass("active_candlestickk");

                        //$("#indicator_list").hide();
                        //$("#indicator_list").removeClass('indicator_list_hover');
                    }


                    else if(type=='candlestick')
                    {
                        $(this).addClass("active_candlestickk");
                        $("#linee").removeClass("active_linee");
                        $("#ohlcc").removeClass("active_ohlcc");

                        //$("#indicator_list").hide();
                        //$("#indicator_list").removeClass('indicator_list_hover');
                    }

                    chart(type,printSma,linked,line,algo,typ);
                });
            });
        });


<div id="chart" class="chart"> 
              <!--<p>Select Chart Type : </p>-->
     <div class="chart_type">
        <div class="border_chart">
        <input type="button" name="selection" value="candlestick" class="candlestickk" id="candlestickk" title="Candle Stick">
        <input type="button" name="selection" value="ohlc" class="ohlcc" id="ohlcc" title="OHLC">
        <input type="button" name="selection" value="line" class="linee" id="linee" title="Line">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't post any part of code, so how could we help you? In general, when you update series (`series.update(options);`) it will redraw chart, otherwise you won't see updated series, right? Dome on jsFiddle would be great.

Comment: @PawełFus : I just updated it with code please see it and let me know if there is a solution.

Comment: Well, your chart get refreshed always when adding some element on a chart, like plotLine or addSeries. Without refresh you wouldn't see any effect on a chart. Now, could you explain what exactly doesn't work? Also, debugging 500 lines of code isn't simple. Could you recreate simple demo on jsFiddle with your issue? Thanks.

Comment: @PawełFus: here is the Jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/7txq9/ ]  .But again when I switch to candlestick or ohlc the chart becomes full blank.

Comment: It's a bug, already reported by Sebastian [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3008)

Comment: So, what should I do? Looks like again I have go back to **re-creating** chart when switches from one to another chart type.

Comment: Yes, for now the only solution is to destroy chart and create from the beginning.