# How to stop resetting zoom when switches to other chart type in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

In highcharts when I switches from one chart type to another type the zoom selection gets reset to 'All'.

In the following picture I have chosen chart type 'Candle Stick' and zoom type '1M'
[image]

Now when I change the chart type to 'Line' the zoom type reset to 'All'

[image]

I want to prevent from changing zoom type from one selection to another when I change chart type. By the way, is it possible to keep those line which I created in one chart type as it is and when I switches to another chart type it shouldn't remove.Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle demonstrating your problem or at the very least show us some code.  In it's current form your question is unanswerable.  I did a quick attempt to reproduce your problem (http://jsfiddle.net/29PZE/) but my zoom remains when I switch series type.

Comment: I already asked somehow similar type of question...please check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680335/stop-redraw-chart-when-chart-types-changes-in-highcharts] if you don't understand the I will create a JSfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked that your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680335/stop-redraw-chart-when-chart-types-changes-in-highcharts) for your code.  The problem is that you aren't **updating** your chart when your series type changes but instead you are **re-creating** the whole chart.  Anything drawn on it or zoom options that have been changed will not be preserved.  So, instead of re-creating the chart, just update it.  For instance to change the series type do:

```
Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].update({'type':type}); // set the first series to a type
```

See this fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/29PZE/1/).

Comment: You are right.its working, but again when I switch to candlestick or ohlc the chart becomes full blank. Any idea why is that occurring?

Comment: Becasue candlestick/ohlc needs to 5 values, instead of 2. In other words you need to have x,open,high,low,close values but in line/column you have only x,y.

Comment: But I have all those values because: I am requesting oanda data from API like this :
`var data='http://api-sandbox.oanda.com/v1/history?instrument=EUR_USD&candleFormat=midpoint&granularity=W';
var datalen=data.candles.length;
for(var i=0; i<datalen;i++)
{
var each=[Date._parse(data.candles[i].time), data.candles[i].openMid, data.candles[i].highMid, data.candles[i].lowMid, data.candles[i].closeMid]
onadata.push(each);
}`
previously when I was **re-creating** the chart whenever I switches from one chart to another it works.

Comment: @SebastianBochan : Please see the fiddle [ http://jsfiddle.net/das_palash89/7txq9/ ].but again when I switch to candlestick or ohlc the chart becomes full blank

Comment: It looks like a bug, reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3008